# php, Curl error: Illegal characters found in URL

Tags: php, парсер, curl

```
<?php

function getUrl($inputSearchPostArray) {
    if (is_array($inputSearchPostArray)) {
        $inputSearchPostString = http_build_query($inputSearchPostArray);
    } else {
        $inputSearchPostString = $inputSearchPostArray;
    }

    $userAgent      = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0';
    $cURL = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL,             "https://www.avito.ru/search");
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HEADER,          TRUE);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,       $userAgent);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,         10);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,  TRUE);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POST,            TRUE);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,      $inputSearchPostString);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,     TRUE);

    $answerFromServer = curl_exec($cURL);

    if (curl_getinfo($cURL, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) != 301) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    $outputUrl = substr($answerFromServer, stripos($answerFromServer, "Location: ") + 10);
    $outputUrl = substr($outputUrl, 0, strpos($outputUrl, "X-Frame-Options:") - 1);

    return 'https://www.avito.ru'.$outputUrl;
}

$test = getUrl($_POST);

echo $test;

$userAgent      = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0';
$cURL           = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL,             $test);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HEADER,          TRUE);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,       $userAgent);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,         10);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,  TRUE);

$answerFromServer = curl_exec($cURL);

if ($answerFromServer === false)
{
  throw new Exception('Curl error: ' . curl_error($cURL));
}

 ?>
```

Функция ровно работает, она ринимает пост запрос который авито отправляет на свои сервера при нажатии кноки найти. Решил затестить. Вот вывод.

https://www.avito.ru/ekaterinburg/avtomobili/s_probegom/bmw/m3?pmax=15000000&pmin=15000&metro=2039-2041-2044&f=188_0b893.1375_0b15524.187_866-869.185_861.186_864.1374_15786b15800.695_8852&i=1

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught Exception: Curl error: Illegal characters found in URL in /root/sites/avito.bot/search.php:58
Stack trace:#0 {main} thrown in /root/sites/avito.bot/search.php 58

Не могу понять какие символы ему не нравятся. В браузере ссылка открывается.

Comment: попробуйте кодировать url при помощи urldecode

Comment: @Oboroten urlencode

Comment: конечно encode )

Comment: получается вот что: 
`Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Curl error: Could not resolve host: https%3A%2F%2Fwww.avito.ru%2Fekaterinburg%2Favtomobili%2Fs_probegom%2Fbmw%2Fm3%3Fpmax%3D15000000%26pmin%3D15000%26metro%3D2039-2041-2044%26f%3D188_0b893.1375_0b15524.187_866-869.185_861.186_864.1374_15786b15800.695_8852%26i%3D1%0D in /root/sites/avito.bot/search.php:58 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /root/sites/avito.bot/search.php on line 58 .` Я уже пробовал

Comment: по такой сылке даже браузер не откроет

Answer (score 1):

Ошибку исправил. Когда функция вычленяла ссылку из страницы с редиректом, то захватывала пробел, а с ним походу еще какие-то скрытые знаки.